# three.js init with object close to camera

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

In my three.js projet i se my scene and camera like thisone:

```
        var container = document.getElementById('container');

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setAnimationLoop(render);
        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
        renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1.25;
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

        stats = new Stats();
        container.appendChild(stats.dom);

        //

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
        camera.position.set(3.5, 2, - 2.5);


        controls = new OrbitControls(camera, container);
        controls.target.set(0, 0.5, 0);
        controls.update();

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xeeeeee);
        scene.environment = new RoomEnvironment(renderer);
        scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xeeeeee, 10, 50);
        ...
```

well my scene start like this:

[image]

i would like to start doubled my object, like this:

[image]

i try:

```
camera.zoom.set(2);
```

but nothing happens
So i try to define a vector3 (2,2,2) and scale my object:

```
myobj.scale.set(myVector3);
```

nothing.

Someone can help me about starting my scene with my object more big?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```js
camera.zoom.set(2);
```

You have to ensure to update the project matrix like so:

```js
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Regarding the other issue, `Vector3.set()` only accepts three scalars as parameters. You can't use the method with a single argument of type `Vector3`. So you can do:

```js
myobj.scale.set(myVector3.x, myVector3.y, myVector3.z);
```

or even better:

```js
myobj.scale.copy(myVector3);
```